# Getting prompted with a GitHub Login Interface whenever I try to push to repo

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-credential-manager, github-cli

this happened around 3 weeks ago, when they said https connections to GitHub would be removed. That's when this Login UI started popping whenever I tried to push, even though I provided the correct username and password, it said it's incorrect. Then prompted me to type it in bash/terminal, still saying it's incorrect.

I setup a SSH key and everything was going well, until I tried to push and the same happened again.

Installed GitHub CLI, setup a brand new repo to test this out, and the problem still persists! Have been searching all over docs and on the internet for the past 3 hours, it's driving me nuts.

Would like you to provide me with a solution guys. Thanks

EDIT: I'm running git version 2.26.0.windows.1

output when `git remote -v` is typed:

```
origin  https://github.com/marjotoska/website-mock-test.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/marjotoska/website-mock-test.git (push)
```

EDIT2:

```
git push
fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin main

git push --set-upstream origin main
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
```

Then the login UI appears just like this, and even though username and password provided are correct, it doesn't log me in.

After that UI fail, login from cmd also fails:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': marjotoska
Password for 'https://marjotoska@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/marjotoska/website-mock-test.git/'
```

I generated SSH key the way it was intended in the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

---

It makes no sense whatsoever that login fails twice, also tried logout->login from the browser and it works just fine with the same credentials. Is there something to be done here?

EDIT3: The website (https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations) GitHub devs point to:

> What you need to do today.
> For developers, if you are using a password to authenticate Git
> operations with GitHub.com today, you must begin using a personal
> access token over HTTPS (recommended) or SSH key by August 13, 2021,
> to avoid disruption. If you receive a warning that you are using an
> outdated third-party integration, you should update your client to the
> latest version.

I'm using SSH over HTTPS, and the problem still persists.

EDIT4: Login with Personal access tokens works!!!

From Github:

> Personal access tokens function like ordinary OAuth access tokens. They can be used instead of a password for Git over HTTPS, or can be used to authenticate to the API over Basic Authentication.

PAT is treated as a password, and I used it in place of my password, which pushed the local repo to the remote one

```
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Username for 'https://github.com': marjotoska
Password for 'https://marjotoska@github.com':
Enumerating objects: 27, done.
Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Writing objects: 100% (27/27), 106.63 KiB | 8.20 MiB/s, done.
Total 27 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
To https://github.com/marjotoska/website-mock-test.git
 * [new branch]      main -> main
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
```

SOLVED!

Comment: What OS and version of Git are you using?  Also, please edit your question to include the output of `git remote -v` as a code block.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide more details: What are the _exact_ error messages or popups that appear?  How did you setup the SSH keys? Which _exact_ commands are you using?

Comment: @bk2204, just updated the question with more details, what's your take on this?

Comment: @Gino Mempin, just updated the question with more details, what's your take on this?

Comment: Hi @jessehouwing , just found out I needed a personal access token, and even answered my own question just so I have it in the future or if some guy has the same problem as I. 

Basically the devs removed password authentication for security reasons and hinted that access tokens are the preferred way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021 for security reasons by the developers. They recommend to use a personal access token instead.

To create a token:

1. From your GitHub account > profile picture > settings
2. Developer settings from the left sidebar > Personal Access Tokens
3. Generate new token.

To use the token:

Replace your password with the token when prompted to login/authenticate.
*Note: PAT doesn't work with UI, but it does from cmd prompt*

To cache your credentials and stop the prompt appearing every time you commit:

```
gh auth login
```

Follow the prompts > set HTTPS as the preferred protocol > paste PAT in the very last step.

Now you're hooked and ready to go

Links: https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login

Answer (score 1):

When you have a recent version of Git installed it offers you to install Git Credential Manager Core, which has all the latest ways to connect to GitHub, BitBucket and Azure DevOps. This is the easiest scenario to use and should work across Windows, Mac and Linux. gcm-core will generate and manage the PAT on your behalf.

If you're using WSL, you may need to install gcm-core there separately and perform a 2nd authorization.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git Credential Manager Core>git-credential-manager-core.exe  --version
2.0.498+7ad55fb809

C:\Program Files\Git\cmd>git --version
git version 2.33.0.windows.1
```

You can download them here, the latest installer for git should come with gcm-core:

- https://git-scm.com/downloads
- https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases/latest

It may be turned off when you run the installer:

[image: Configure gcm-core in the installer of git]

It is possible your git configuration is looking at the older, no longer maintained, Git Credential Manager for Windows, in which care you may have to force it over to the more recent version:

Run `git-credential-manager-core configure` to have it self-register in your global git config:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git Credential Manager Core>git-credential-manager-core.exe configure
Configuring component 'Git Credential Manager'...
Configuring component 'Azure Repos provider'...
```

Your passwords will be stored in the Windows Credential Manager,

[image: Windows Credential Manager showing git credentials]

If you run into issues, clearing them there may get Git to prompt for fresh creds:

[image: Remove item from Windows credential manager by expanding the item and clicking "remove"]

Cloning will now prompt Git to open an auth prompt:

[image: Github auth prompt popping up in windows]

You can either enter a PAT token here, or authorize Git Credential Manager Core to manage the PAT tokens locally on your behalf. It will open a browser for you or write a URL to the prompt for you to perform the auth against:

[image: Authorize Git Credential Manager Core]

You may be prompted to verify your identity:

[image: Verify your identity]

And then cloning, pushing or whatever else you do should work as expected:

[image: Succestul clone]

You should now see a new or updated entry in the Windows Credential Manager:

[image: Windows credential manager showing fresh creds]

Answer (score -2):

```
git config --global user.email "your github email"
git config --global user.name "your user name on github"
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/your repo name.git

those may work
```